# Reduce space before and after an environment

Tags: spacing, environments

A simple(?) question, how do I reduce the space before and after a environment?

I suppose I'm after a redefine environment command that I can put at the top of my document.

**Example**

I'm using Sweave and the R highlight environment. Basically, R code gets transformed into latex code. The end latex result looks like this:

```
\begin{Hchunk}
  \begin{Hinput}
     \ttfamily\noindent
     \hlprompt{\usebox{\hlnormalsizeboxgreaterthan}{\ }}<snip>
     \normalfont
   \end{Hinput}

   \begin{Houtput}
     \ttfamily\noindent
      NC-17{\ }{\ }{\ }{\ }PG{\ }PG-13{\ }{\ }{\ }{\ }{\ }<snip>
   \end{Houtput}

 %A few more Hinput and Houtput environments.
\end{Hchunk}
```

I would like to reduce the space after `\end{Houtput}` For example `\end{Houtput}\vspace{-0.2em}`

Comment: Could you post a small example code showing exactly which space do you want to reduce? Also which environment are you trying to redefine?

Comment: The `highlight` package documentation says that you should just redefine `Hinput` and `Houtput` as you desire. Note that using a negative `\vspace` is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @TH: If vspace is the wrong thing to do, what's the correct thing to do, i.e. how do you redefine Hinput? Or is this another question?

Comment: I answered this several days ago. Use `\renewenvironment` to change the definition of the `Hchunk` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The highlight package seems to define

```
\newenvironment{Hinput}{}{}
\newenvironment{Houtput{}{}
\newenvironment{Hchunk}{%
\vspace{0.5em}\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\highlightbox}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.9\textwidth}%
}{%
\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
\fcolorbox{highlightBorder}{highlightBg}{\usebox{\highlightbox}}%
\vspace{0.5em}
}
```

You can change those to be more suitable to what you want. In particular, you can remove the `\vspace`. Just use `\renewenvironment`.